# Closing and reopening port immediately

Tags: sockets, tcp

While programming for sockets I came across a doubt on usage of **setsocketopt()**. If we provide

```
setsockopt( socket_no, SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR , (char *) &optval, (socklength) sizeof( optval ) );//To reuse addr
```

Followed by another socket option for the same socket,

```
setsockopt( socket_no, IPPROTO_IPV6,IPV6_V6ONLY , (char *) &optval, (socklength) sizeof( optval ) );//To use only IPv6
```

*(1)Does setting socket option again, removes the reuse address option which is set already ?*

In few situation, there is a need to close and reopen a static port immediately without any delay.

*(2)Does closing and reopening a port immediately causes  problem ?*

*(3)If closing and reopening a port immediately causes problem, can it be avoided using SO_REUSEPORT/SO_REUSEADDR in socket option. As it overcomes time_wait set by TCP protocol. Or is there some alternative to overcome this problem ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1)Does setting socket option again, removes the reuse address option which is set already ?

No. Each socket option is independent.

> (2)Does closing and reopening a port immediately causes problem ?

No, not unless there was at least one TCP connection to or from that port recently.

> (3)If closing and reopening a port immediately causes problem, can it be avoided using SO_REUSEPORT/SO_REUSEADDR in socket option. As it overcomes time_wait set by TCP protocol. Or is there some alternative to overcome this problem ?

It has no effect on time_wait. It just lets you re-open the port immediately. The existing connection is unaffected and continues to timeout normally, it just doesn't prevent you from re-opening the port.

Comment: on (2) if there is a recent connection to the same port, then reopening the port immediately causes problem ??

Comment: @user4402433 Yes. Information about the connection may remain to handle the completion of the close operation and if you don't set SO_REUSEPORT, that will inhibit re-opening the port.